# If $\left(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^{a}\right)^b=1^c+2^c+\cdots+n^c$ for some $n$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$?

Tags: number-theory, summation

**Question** : Is the following conjecture true?

**Conjecture** : Let $a,b(\ge 2),c,n(\ge 2)$ be natural numbers. If $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^a\right)^b=\sum_{k=1}^nk^c\ \ \ \ \ \cdots(\star)$$
for **some** $n$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3).$

**Remark 1** : What I'm asking is if **each** of the followings is true :
$$\text{If $(1^a+2^a)^b=1^c+2^c$ for $a,b(\ge 2),c\in\mathbb N$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$$

$$\text{If $(1^a+2^a+3^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c$ for $a,b(\ge 2),c\in\mathbb N$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$$

$$\text{If $(1^a+2^a+3^a+4^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c+4^c$ for $a,b(\ge 2),c\in\mathbb N$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$$
$$\vdots$$

**Remark 2** : I'm **not** asking if the following is true :

$\text{If for $a,b(\ge 2),c\in\mathbb N$},$$$(1^a+2^a)^b=1^c+2^c,$$
$$(1^a+2^a+3^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c,$$
$$(1^a+2^a+3^a+4^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c+4^c,$$
$$\vdots$$
then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3).$

**Motivation** : This question comes from
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3.$$

This got me interested in $(\star)$. I've got the followings :

*1.* If $(\star)$ for **any** $n\in\mathbb N$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3).$

We can easily prove this by considering the limitation $n\to\infty$ of the both sides of 
$$\frac{n^{(a+1)b}}{n^{c+1}}\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1n\left(\frac kn\right)^a\right\}^b=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1n \left(\frac kn\right)^c.$$

*2.* If $(\star)$ for $n=2$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3).$

Expanding LHS of $(1+2^a)^b=1+2^c$ gives us that $b$ is even. Setting $b=2d$, we have $((1+2^a)^d-1)((1+2^a)^d+1)=2^c\Rightarrow (1+2^a)^d-1=2^e,(1+2^a)^d+1=2^f$. Then, since we have $2^f-2^e=2$, we have $(e,f)=(1,2)$. These lead $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

*3.* If $(\star)$ for $n=3$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3).$

In the following, I'm going to prove *3*.

**Proof** : Supposing $c\le ab$, since $b\ge 2$, we get
$$(1+2^a+3^a)^b=1+2^{ab}+3^{ab}+\cdots\gt 1+2^c+3^c.$$ This is a contradiction. Hence, $c\gt ab$. Supposing $b\ge 3$, we get $c\gt ab\ge 3$.

Here, since $3^c+1\equiv 4,2$ (mod $8$) for any $c\in\mathbb N$, $3^c+1$ is not a multiple of $8$. By the way, since $1+2^a+3^a$ is even, $(1+2^a+3^a)^b$ is a multiple of $8$. Since $2^c$ is a multiple of $8$, this leads that $3^c+1$ is a multiple of $8$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $b=2, c\gt 2a$.

If $a\ge 3$, since
$$\left(\frac 23\right)^a+\left(\frac 13\right)^a\le\left(\frac 23\right)^3+\left(\frac 13\right)^3=\frac13,$$
$2^a+1\le \frac{3^a}{3}.$ Hence, 
$$3^c\lt 1+2^c+3^c=(1+2^a+3^a)^2\le \left(\frac{3^a}{3}+3^a\right)^2=3^{2a}\left(\frac 43\right)^2=3^{2a}\cdot\frac {16}{9}\lt 3^{2a+1}.$$
$3^c\lt 3^{2a+1}$ leads $0\lt c-2a\lt 1$, which means that $c-2a$ is not an integer. This is a contradiction. Hence, we know $a=1$ or $a=2$.

The $(a,b)=(1,2)$ case leads $c=3$.

The $(a,b)=(2,2)$ case leads $c\ge5\Rightarrow 1+2^c+3^c\gt 196$, which is a contradiction. Now the proof is completed.

After getting these results, I reached the above conjecture. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144208/if-left1a2a-cdotsna-rightb-1c2c-cdotsnc-for-some-n-then).

Comment: One number is not likely to suffice, you are just lucky it worked for small $n$. In general you have function $f(a, b, n)$ on the LHS and other $g(c, n)$ on the RHS and in general there is no reason why they shouldn't agree at some $n$ for some choice of the parameters. It should be easy to write a program that finds these counterexamples for small values of $n$.

Comment: I assume you know of this paper <http://www.jstor.org/stable/3609189> by Edmond?

Comment: @Marek: I think so, but I haven't got any counterexample so far. Please let me know if you get the one.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want it to hold for some $n$, and not all $n$ right?

Comment: Ah thanks, missed that :)

Comment: This inequality might help establish bounds:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality

Comment: @KieranCooney: Thanks, but I'm not sure this is helpful so far.

Comment: After a quick test with C+GMP, your conjecture seems to hold for every $a,c,n\le100$

Comment: For some $n\gt1$, I assume.

Comment: More interesting question: Does there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \; $ such that, $ ( \zeta (-a))^b = \zeta (-c) $

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial solution. I've just been able to get the following theorem:

**Theorem** : If $(\star)$ for some $n=8k-5,8k-4\ (k\in\mathbb N)$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

**Lemma** : For $a\ge 2, n\ge 2,$
$$\left(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a\right)^2\lt 1^{2a+1}+2^{2a+1}+\cdots+n^{2a+1}.$$

**Proof for Lemma** : Let $L(n), R(n)$ be the left hand side and the right hand side respectively. Note that $L(1)=R(1)$ for any $a$. By the way, since
$$L(n+1)-L(n)=(n+1)^a\left\{(n+1)^a+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^a\right\},R(n+1)-R(n)=(n+1)^{2a+1},$$
we get
$$\{R(n+1)-R(n)\}-\{L(n+1)-L(n)\}=(n+1)^{a}\left\{(n+1)^{a+1}-(n+1)^a-2\sum_{k=1}^nk^a\right\}$$
$$=(n+1)^a\left\{n(n+1)^a-2\sum_{k=1}^nk^a\right\}=(n+1)^{2a}\left\{n-2\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a\right\}.$$
Here, since $a\ge 2$, we get
$$2\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a+\left(\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}\right)^a\right\}\lt\sum_{k=1}^n1=n.$$
Hence, we know 
$$\{R(n+1)-R(n)\}-\{L(n+1)-L(n)\}\gt0\iff R(n+1)-L(n+1)\gt R(n)-L(n).$$
With $L(1)=R(1)$, the proof for lemma is completed.

**Proof for Theorem** : Supposing $c\le ab$, since $b\ge 2$, we get
$$(1+2^a+\cdots+n^a)^b=\left(1+2^{ab}+3^{ab}+\cdots+n^{ab}\right)+\cdots\gt 1+2^c+\cdots+n^c.$$ This is a contradiction. Hence, $c\gt ab$.

Supposing $b\ge 3$, we get $c\gt ab\ge 3$. For $n=8k-5,8k-4\ (k\in\mathbb N)$, considering in mod $8$, since $1+2^a+\cdots+n^a$ is even, we have $$(1+2^a+\cdots+n^a)^b\equiv 0.$$
However, the right hand side of $(\star)$ is not a multiple of $8$. Let us prove this.

Note that $1^{2m-1}\equiv 1, 3^{2m-1}\equiv 3, 5^{2m-1}\equiv 5, 7^{2m-1}\equiv 7$ and that $1^{2m}\equiv 3^{2m}\equiv 5^{2m}\equiv 7^{2m}\equiv 1$ (mod $8$) for any $m\in\mathbb N$.

$(1)$ The $c=2m-1$ case : Noting that $(\text{even})^c\equiv 0$ for $c\ge 3$,
$$RHS\equiv 1+3+5+\cdots+(8k-5)=\sum_{i=1}^{4k-2}(2i-1)\equiv 4\not\equiv 0.$$

$(2)$ The $c=2m$ case : We have
$$RHS\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{4k-2}1=4k-2\not \equiv 0.$$
$(1)(2)$ tells us that the right hand side of $(\star)$ is not a multiple of $8$ for any $c$. This is a contradiction. Hence, we know $b=2, c\gt 2a$.

Supposing $a\ge 3$, since
$$\left(\frac 1n\right)^a+\left(\frac 2n\right)^a+\cdots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^a\le\left(\frac 1n\right)^3+\left(\frac 2n\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^3=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n},$$
we get
$$1^a+2^a+\cdots+(n-1)^a\le\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}\times n^a.$$ 
Hence, 
$$n^c\lt 1+2^c+3^c+\cdots+n^c=(1+2^a+3^a+\cdots+n^a)^2\le \left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}\times n^a+n^a\right)^2=n^{2a}\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}+1\right)^2=n^{2a}\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n}\right)^2\lt n^{2a+2}.$$
This is because $\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n}\right)^2\lt n^2\iff \frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n}\lt n\iff (n-1)(3n+1)\gt0\iff n\ge 2$.
Hence, $n^c\lt n^{2a+2}$ leads $0\lt c-2a\lt 2$, which means that $c-2a=1\iff c=2a+1$. However, the above lemma tells us that this case has no solution. Hence, we know $a\le 2$.

The $(a,b)=(1,2)$ case leads $c=3$.

The $(a,b)=(2,2)$ case leads $(1+2^2+\cdots+n^2)^2=\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)^2=1+2^c+\cdots+n^c$. However, since we can easily prove that
$$\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)^2\lt 1^5+2^5+\cdots+n^5=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}{12}$$
for $n\ge 2$, this case leads a contradiction.

Now, the proof for Theorem is completed.

**PS**: This idea (using mod $8$) does not seem to work for the other $n$. Another idea would be needed.

Comment: for any postive $n$?

Comment: @math110: No. Please see the remarks added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

let $$S_{r}(n)=1^r+2^r+3^r+\cdots+n^r$$
It is well know
$$\dfrac{n^{r+1}}{r+1}\le S_{r}(n)\le\dfrac{(n+1)^{r+1}}{r+1}$$
since
$$S_{c}(n)=(S_{a}(n))^b$$
so
$$\dfrac{n^{c+1}}{c+1}\le S_{c}(n)=(S_{a}(n))^b\le\left[\dfrac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]^{b}$$
so
$$\dfrac{n^{c+1}}{c+1}\le\left[\dfrac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]^b$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{(a+1)^b}{c+1}\le\dfrac{(n+1)^{(a+1)b}}{n^{c+1}}$$
simaler we have
$$\left(\dfrac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}\right)^b\le (S_{a}(n))^b=S_{c}(n)=\le\dfrac{(n+1)^{c+1}}{c+1}$$
so
$$\dfrac{(a+1)^b}{c+1}\ge\dfrac{n^{(a+1)b}}{(n+1)^{c+1}}$$
so
$$\dfrac{n^{(a+1)b}}{(n+1)^{c+1}}\le\dfrac{(a+1)^b}{c+1}\le\dfrac{(n+1)^{(a+1)b}}{n^{c+1}}$$
let $n\to\infty$,then we have
$$(a+1)b=c+1, (a+1)^b=c+1$$
since $a,b\ge 2$,so
$$b=(a+1)^{b-1}\ge 2^{b-1}$$
so we must have $b=2,a=1,c=3$

Comment: This does not answer my question. Please see the remarks added in the question.

Comment: You cannot take $n\to\infty$ because $S_c(n)=(S_a(n))^b$ holds for a $n$, not for any $n$.