# Does $(1^a+2^a+3^a+4^a+5^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c+4^c+5^c$ imply $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, exponentiation

> **Question** : Is the following proposition true?
>
> **Proposition** : For positive integers $a,b,c$ where $b\ge 2$, if
> $$(1^a+2^a+3^a+4^a+5^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c+4^c+5^c$$then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

This is an unsolved case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508780/if-left1a2a-cdotsna-rightb-1c2c-cdotsnc-for-some-n-then) where it has been proven that each of the following propositions is true for positive integers $a,b,c$ where $b\ge 2$ :

- $\text{If $(1^a+2^a)^b=1^c+2^c$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$
- $\text{If $(1^a+2^a+3^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$
- $\text{If $(1^a+2^a+3^a+4^a)^b=1^c+2^c+3^c+4^c$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$
- $\text{If $(1^a+2^a+\cdots +{11}^a)^b=1^c+2^c+\cdots+11^c$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$
- $\text{If $(1^a+2^a+\cdots +{12}^a)^b=1^c+2^c+\cdots+12^c$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.}$

$$\vdots$$

I've been trying to use mod and some inequalities, but every attempt has failed. Can anyone help?

**Added** : I'm going to add the background of this question.

We know that
$$\left(1^1+2^1+\cdots+n^1\right)^2=1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$$
holds for **every** $n\in\mathbb N$. Also, it is known that, for positive integers $a,b,c$ where $b\ge 2$, if
$$\left(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a\right)^b=1^c+2^c+\cdots+n^c$$
holds for **every** $n\in\mathbb N$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

Then, I've been interested in the following similar, but completely different question :

> For positive integers $a,b,c$ where $b\ge 2$, if
> $$\left(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a\right)^b=1^c+2^c+\cdots+n^c$$
> holds for **a specific** $n\color{red}{\ge 2}\in\mathbb N$, then can we say that $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$?

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508780/if-left1a2a-cdotsna-rightb-1c2c-cdotsnc-for-some-n-then). It has been proven that the answer is **yes** for $n=2,8k-5,8k-4$ where $k\in\mathbb N$.

However, the question has not received any complete answers. For example, it is not known if the answer is yes for $n=5$, which is the smallest unsolved case I'm asking here.

Comment: From identical equation: $(1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3)\equiv(1+2+3+...+n)^2$?

Comment: @chenyuandong: If $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$, then we can have $(1+2+3+4+5)^2=1^3+2^3+4^3+5^3$. But my question is about the converse : I'm asking if $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

In general we have

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n k^a = \frac{1}{a+1} \prod_{\jmath=1}^{a+1} \big( n + n_\jmath\big)
> \tag 1
> $$

Examples

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \sum_{k=1}^n k &=& \frac{1}{2} n \big( n + 1 \big)\\\
> \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 &=& \frac{1}{3} n \big( n + 1 \big) \big( n + 1/2 \big)\\\
> \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 &=& \frac{1}{4} n^2 \big( n + 1 \big)^2\\\
> \sum_{k=1}^n k^4 &=& \frac{1}{5} n \big( n + 1 \big)
>    \big( n + 1/2 \big)
>    \Big( n + 1/2 - \sqrt{7/12} \Big)
>    \Big( n + 1/2 + \sqrt{7/12} \Big)
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

So we can only get

> $$
> \left( \sum_{k=1}^n k^a \right)^b = \sum_{k=1}^n k^c,\\
> \quad \textrm{if at least} \quad
> \left( \frac{1}{a+1} \right)^b = \frac{1}{1+c},
> \quad \textrm{and} \quad
> \big( a + 1 \big) b = c + 1. \tag 2
> $$

So the question is, when do we have
$$
\big( a + 1 \big)^{b-1} = b ?
$$

So only $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=3$ are the solutions.

Comment: I don't believe that the OP is looking for a polynomial identity (it is easy to show that there are no others). I suspect he (or perhaps she) simply wants to rule out the existence of quadruples $(a,b,c,n)$ for which $(\sum_{k=1}^n k^a)^b=\sum_{k=1}^n k^c$ with $(a,b,c) \neq (1,2,3)$, a rather subtler problem.

Comment: @MikeBennett, I added the *tags* - look for tag $(2)$... And if you have an alternative solution - you are free to post ;)

Comment: @johannesvalks: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid that yours does not answer my question. I know that if $(2)$ holds for every $n$, then $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$, which I think your answer shows. But this is not what I'm asking. What I'm asking is that if $(2)$ holds for an $n$, for example, $n=5$, then can we say that $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$?

Comment: @mathlove - I see now what you mean. You ask for a specific value. Not every - but a specific $n$... Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @johannesvalks: Yes, that's what I meant. Anyway, thank you for taking your time to consider my question.